# Finding which rev more closely matches a given code

Tags: mercurial

This has happened to me a couple of times:

I find a zip with an unversioned snapshot of the source code (ie: the `.hg` folder was not included in the zip, or was removed). For varying reasons, I've had to figure out *which* Rev this code belongs to. Or which rev matches it "more closely", if the *exact* match is somewhere between 2 revs.

**How can I find which rev more closely matches a given code?**

I suppose I could write a script that cycles through every rev and counts the number of diff lines, but I wonder if this already exists.

Maybe some hg internal command is already able to do it? (and could do it a lot more efficiently that I could accomplish in a script)

Comment: I would try it exactly the way you suggest yourself: commit that version. And then make a small script which checks the size of the diff to all others, finding the minimum number of diff lines (which is not necessarily the same as size of diff, if you happen to have binary)